# Bash if... then... syntax error

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I am trying to remove something based on user input using bash/sh, here is my code :

```
echo "remove ? [Y/n]"
read REMOVE
if [ $REMOVE != "n" ] || [ $REMOVE !="N" ];then
  # ... do something ...
  echo "done"
fi
```

the error I am getting is something like:

> ./run.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected symbol « then »
>
> ./run.sh: line 8: `if [ $REMOVE != "n" ] || [ $REMOVE !="N" ];then'

I tried to add/remove spaces many times, and I still don't understand what happens. I also don't really understand all the differences between `[[ statement ]]` `[statement]` or `((statement))`.
If someone can help...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691082/why-am-i-getting-a-unary-operator-expected-error

Comment: @fvu `$SHELL` is zsh but the script is actually running in bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
echo "remove ? [Y/n]"
read REMOVE
if [ $REMOVE != "n" ] && [ $REMOVE != "N" ]
then
  # ... do something ...
  echo "done"
fi
```

Comment: `./run.sh: line 8 : [: n : expected unary operator`

(maybe it's not the english output, I translated it myself)

Comment: As far as the logic which you are trying to achieve, I feel you should be using `&&` and not `||`

Comment: Better yet: `if [ x"$REMOVE" != xn -a x"$REMOVE" != xN ]; then ...`.

Comment: The `x` is not needed as long as you quote the `$` variable -- although the answer is accepted it is erroneous and a timebomb waiting to blow

Answer (score 2):

In your original problem, you need a space here

```
$REMOVE != "N"
```

In your comment response to shruti1810, it sounds like your `$REMOVE` variable doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Try adding

```
echo $REMOVE
```

to your script.

I typically use this construct

```
if [ "x$REMOVE" != "xn" ] || [ "x$REMOVE" != "xN" ]
then
  # ... do something ...
  echo "done"
fi
```

to ensure that my arguments are both valid.

Answer (score 1):

Quote the "$REMOVE" and insert space around the "!=" -- like this;

```
if [ "$REMOVE" != "n" ] || [ "$REMOVE" != "N" ];then
  # ... do something ...
  echo "done"
fi
```

The problem is that is REMOVE is not set or if it is set to an empty string (like if you just press return on the 'read') you will get $REMOVE substituted to nothing and your expression would look like  `[ != "N" ]` which will produce an `unary operator expected` error.